# How to set HTTP password in gerrit while making a REST call using python-requests?

Tags: rest, authentication, python-requests, gerrit

Using requests module want to query Gerrit server and for this need set authentication in below code. And this needs to be done without using any other module like pygerrit2. And if this can be done using HTTP password generated from gerrit. If this is not doable, share an example if auth has to be passed along with Get request.

```
import requests
import json
import os

GERRIT_SERVER = 'https://gerrit.abc.com'

class GerritServer():

  def __init__(self):
    self._base_url = GERRIT_SERVER

    self._endpoints = {
      'CHANGES': 'changes',
    }

  def _get_endpoint(self, token):
    try:
      endpoint = self._endpoints[token]
    except ValueError:
      raise Exception('endpoint not defined for {0}'.format(token))

    return '{0}/{1}'.format(self._base_url, endpoint)

  def get_endpoint_changes(self):
    return self._get_endpoint('CHANGES')
```

Answer (score 0):

Gerrit's REST API uses digest auth.

```
username = 'foo'
httpassword = 'bar'
api = 'baz'
auth = requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth(username, httpassword)
r = requests.get(api, auth=auth)
```